# r- access to lists of lists

Tags: r, list

I need to access to each element of a list inside a list. Let's say my lists are:

```
improve<-c('30/0', '60/0', '60/30', '90/60', '90/30', '90/0')
maintein<-c('0/0', '30/30', '60/60', '90/90')
worsen<-c('0/30', '30/60', '60/90', '60/NA', '90/NA')
```

And my final list is:

```
lista<-list(improve, maintein, worsen)
```

I need to do sth with each element:

```
for (k in lista) {
 print(k)
  for (i in lista[k]) {
     print(i)
   }
}
```

But I get NULL instead:

```
[1] "30/0"  "60/0"  "60/30" "90/60" "90/30" "90/0" 
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
[1] "0/0"   "30/30" "60/60" "90/90"
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

and so on...
 How can I do to print each element of the insider lists?
Thanks.

Comment: The "[" function does NOT deliver the elements of a list. It delivers a sublist. If you wnat the actual elements, then use "[[".

Comment: @BondedDust is totally right, but that's not the core of the problem here. See answer :-)

Comment: I disagree.  See answer :-)

Comment: @BondedDust: Well that works too - Cheers :-)

Comment: Another option would be to use `as.list(c(improve, maintein, worsen))` to build the new list instead of creating a list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice here:

```
for (k in lista) {
 print(k)
  for (i in lista[k]) {
     print(i)
   }
}
```

The loop variable `k` is a vector since you are iterating over lista, which is a list of vectors.

So this instead:

```
for (k in lista) {
 print(k)
  for (i in k) {
     print(i)
   }
}
```

Will most likely be the correct version you need.

Comment: yes, your code works. thanks! But why lista[k], doesn't work? if it is a vector, and I want to iterate over each element of it?

Comment: k is not an index - it's a list, thus you can loop over it but not indexing lista. You can make it loop over the index also, as in the other answer (note that the output at the outer level loop is slightly different though, since that prints out the number instead of the list).

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
for (k in seq_along(lista) ) {  # safer than 1:length(lista)
 print(k)
  for (i in lista[[k]]) {
     print(i)
   }
}
```

Or:

```
> for (k in seq_along(lista) ) {
+  print(k)
+   for (i in seq_along( lista[[k]] ) ) {
+      print(lista[[k]][i])
+    }
+ }
[1] 1
[1] "30/0"
[1] "60/0"
[1] "60/30"
[1] "90/60"
[1] "90/30"
[1] "90/0"
[1] 2
[1] "0/0"
[1] "30/30"
[1] "60/60"
[1] "90/90"
[1] 3
[1] "0/30"
[1] "30/60"
[1] "60/90"
[1] "60/NA"
[1] "90/NA"
```